# What is "mineral spirits"?

Tags: nomenclature, molecules, identification

I'm working in a project, and for a specific thing, I need to work on a possible recovery of $\ce{HCl}$ in aqueous phase. I found a [patent](https://data.epo.org/publication-server/rest/v1.0/publication-dates/19930922/patents/EP0561554NWA1/document.pdf) on the net in which they use an amine to make a complex with $\ce{HCl}$.

They say in the summary:

> - where a complex between the
> - tertiary amine and the methyl chloride is formed, a hydrocarbon
> - solvent, such as **mineral spirits**, is added to the phase containing the
> - complex and the complex is then thermally dissociated.

I have never heard about that until yet.

I did some research on Sigma-Aldrich and I found [that](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/Graphics/COfAInfo/SigmaSAPQM/SPEC/26/262560/262560-BULK_______SIAL_____.pdf) but I have not too much information, if you have ever heard about that can you please tell me a bit more about? Is that a molecule or a mixture?

Comment: It is a solvent mixture, commonly used as a solvent/thinner of oil-based paints. Since those disappeared from use decades ago, it is not surprising that you did not recognize the name. But, once upon a time, one could buy gallons of mineral spirits at the hardware store.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mineral spirits goes by many names, including "white spirit" and "paint thinner", and is basically just a hydrocarbon solvent mixture. According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_spirit):

> White spirit is a mixture of aliphatic and alicyclic C7 to C12 hydrocarbons with a maximum content of 25% of C7 to C12 aromatic hydrocarbons. A typical composition for mineral spirits is > 65% C10 or higher hydrocarbons,[6] aliphatic solvent hexane, and a maximum benzene content of 0.1% by volume, a kauri-butanol value of 29, an initial boiling point of 145 °C (293 °F) to 174 °C (345 °F), and a density of 0.79 g/ml.

There are also three different types based on whether or not it's undergone processing to remove sulfur, solvent extraction or hydrogenation. Then each type has a separate grade: low flash, regular and high flash grades. So with three different types each having three different grades, there are nine different sorts of mixtures that "officially" fall under the term white spirits, or mineral spirits.

Comment: minerals spirits are also called ligroin, naphta, or petroleum ether. Its a matter of favorites